# Using Windows 10 laptop to watch Amazon Fire TV

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, tv

Netflix can stream in 4k, but only if you use a [dedicated hardware DRM decoder](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/13444).

The prime candidate is [Amazon Fire TV](http://www.amazon.co.uk/All-New-Amazon-Fire-TV-Ultra/dp/B00UH2O6T2), but it seems it is designed to plug in via HDMI.

Thus my question: is there any way to a device like Amazon Fire TV but view the stream on my Windows 10 laptop? I have USB-C, could this be employed with its DisplayPort compatibility in some way?

Answer (score 0):

After posting this I did find something that may well end up being my own answer, albeit horrendously expensive (at least the option I found):

**[USB HDMI Video Capture Card](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1073122-REG/inogeni_4k2usb3_4k_hdmi_to_usb.html)**

[image]

Essentially you plug in the HDMI one end, and USB 3.0 the other and voila, it functions like a web-cam to view the video on your PC.

I am unsure how this will function with DRM content, however.